# Spring Kafka Listner | Read same messages

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a topic name "user" where userid will be dropped, I want to read from this topic and process below functionalities

```
1. process user leave data
2. process user salary data
```

I want to have two listeners pointing to the same topic and read the same user id and initiate processing in parallel.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.user}",group="abc"))
            public void receive(String message) {

                    userService.processLeave(message);
                }

@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.user}",group="abc1"))
            public void receive1(String message) {

                    userService.processPayRoll(message);
                }
```

but all the time I see that -- **processPayRoll** is getting invoked all the time.

what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looks like you use the old Spring Kafka version.

Unfortunately that `group` isn't related to the consumer's `group.id`.
That is `containerGroup` for lifecycle management.

You should consider to configure different `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` based on different consumer configs. And there you already will configure different `ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG`.

The newest version has the `@KafkaListener` structure like:

```
/**
 * If provided, the listener container for this listener will be added to a bean
 * with this value as its name, of type {@code Collection<MessageListenerContainer>}.
 * This allows, for example, iteration over the collection to start/stop a subset
 * of containers.
 * @return the bean name for the group.
 */
String containerGroup() default "";

/**
 * Override the {@code group.id} property for the consumer factory with this value
 * for this listener only.
 * @return the group id.
 * @since 1.3
 */
String groupId() default "";

/**
 * When {@link #groupId() groupId} is not provided, use the {@link #id() id} (if
 * provided) as the {@code group.id} property for the consumer. Set to false, to use
 * the {@code group.id} from the consumer factory.
 * @return false to disable.
 * @since 1.3
 */
boolean idIsGroup() default true;
```

Comment: The 1.3.0.RC1 release candidate is available now in the spring milestone repo; the release is expected to be near the end of the month.